# CodeIgniter: Password Validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, passwords

I'm having a problem with my validation. I'm using Codeigniter's Native Form Validation.

I'm doing a user update feature but, I fail to validate the `oldpassword`. Whenever I type correct value of `oldpassword`, it fails to submit. But when I type it incorrectly, it went good.

Well, this is a part of the controller

```
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('oldpassword', 'Old Password', 'required|callback_password_check');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'New Password', 'required|matches[confirmpassword]');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', 'New Password Confirmation', 'required');
```

and this is the password checker function

```
function password_check($str){

    $result = $this->create_model->check_password($str);
     
       if($result)
       {         
         $this->form_validation->set_message('password_check', 'Password does not match!');
         return false;
       }
    else{
        
        return true;
    }       
}
```

and this is the model of the checker

```
function check_password($str){

         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->from('users');
         $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));          
         $this->db->limit(1);

         $query = $this->db-> get();

         if($query->num_rows() == 1)   {

             //GETS PASSWORD FOR HASHING
             foreach($query->result() as $rows)    {
                $hash = $rows->password;
             }         
             //VERIFY PASSWORD
             if (password_verify($str, $hash)) {
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Success! You have changed the password');    //DONT MIND THIS, ITS A TEST          
                   return true;
              } else {
                  $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Old Password is incorrect'); //DONT MIND THIS, ITS A TEST 
                  return false;
              }

          } else   {

           return false;

         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You condition is incorrect in `function password_check($str)`. Replace

```
if($result)
```

to

```
if(!$result)
```

Comment: So you think this page should be closed as Off-topic Typo?